# Convert any unicode string to corresponding virtual key (scan-) codes

Tags: python

Is it a way in Python to convert any unicode string to key codes (on a keyboard) which is required the string to be typed?

Say, if English 'h' and Russian 'р' are both typed by one key then these keys must have the same codes.

In result I need string representation as array of the key codes.

Comment: I'm confused. If I press that example key, will I get a `h` or a `p`?

Comment: The problem as I see it is that different keyboard setups will have different combinations. Character input is read from keyboard scan codes and filtered by things like locale settings and OS. For a specific set of keyboard builds you could have a dictionary - key = unicode value, value = scan code. You can get the scan codes for *your* keyboard by turning on raw output - see [here where some is trying to read scan codes](http://grokbase.com/t/python/python-list/037qcw9cdt/reading-keyboard-scan-codes)

Comment: @usr2564301 You are right, probably I have to set up keyboard defaults. Depends of your keyboard, depends of your language settings. But - with the settings - how? I don't want to hardcode these defaults for all possible keyboard settings.

Comment: For a standard US or UK English keyboard, there's a lot of unicode characters that cannot be represented by one key and must be entered by using Unicode mode - GEdit for instance uses Shift + Ctrl + u, then u2605 is the Unicode entry for a black star.

Comment: @Alan Yes, but if you specify the defaults (aka "Text Entry Settings") you should get all you want - even Chinese symbols.

Comment: @usr2564301 'p' is a just Russian character which has different code from 'p' but looks exactly the same.

Comment: @usr2564301 I mean something like the next: http://keycode.info/. Try to set up another keyboard language in your OS and you get the exactly same value in event.which when you press the same key in both cases (say, US and German) but event.key could be different.

Comment: Whatever this is to do, it will be *extremely* OS dependent. I highly doubt there is any way *possible* that is OS-independent, and even for a known platform such as Windows it would need to hook deep into the guts of the responsible system drivers. Of which there are several layers.

Answer (score 2):

Given that there is a large number of keyboard layouts out there, you would need a way to have an answer to the question "which keyboard map to use?". For example, on a US keyboard, "Q" is scancode 24, but on a French one, the same letter is on a different scan code (and "A" -> 24 instead).

You could limit this to the keyboard layout(s) installed on the host that you run this on. Then, for any character that can be typed on **that host**, you can find which key it came from (assuming you don't have two layouts that have the same letters, but on different locations - e.g., US (qwerty) and French or Dvorak).

The way you get the key maps is specific to the OS, e.g., if this is a desktop with XOrg driving display and keyboard, you could run `xmodmap -pk` and read its output. It has the list of all keycodes and all characters they map to (one line per key code, with several characters that it maps to). Use the `subprocess` module to run `xmodmap` or whatever utility your OS has to get the keymaps and read it into your program.

Comment: The idea, but I think it could be done more explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

Use getch to get key reference then use function ord to get the number equivalent to this caracter

```
ord(getch())
```

Keep in mind the number and button probabily changed based on user keyboard

Comment: I'm sorry, but how can it help to transform a unicode character into scancode without entering?

Comment: Such a function only switches between a character's numerical code and the same character as a string. It has nothing to do with "keyboard entry" – the two values you are switching between mean exactly the same thing, irrespective of where they came from.

Comment: When you press the button from this key the function will get the correspondent reference to this button, so that way you gonna get "Say, if English 'h' and Russian 'р' are both typed by one key then these keys must have the same codes." so with that just convert it to anything you want ,-,